# Display "Page x of x" in toolbar: category pages and search results

Tags: php, toolbar

I'm looking for a way to display "page x of x" in the toolbar portion of category and search results pages. When the products exceed the amount specified in the "results per page" filter, an ordered list of numbers is rendered, displaying the number of pages in product results. I need to display page numbers, not number of products.

This template is rendered from /templates/page/html/pager.phtml.

Can't find any info on this, have looked all over Google, Magento and StackExchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template you mention is associated with the block `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager`. If you take a look at the block you will find the methods `getCurrentPage` and `getLastPageNum`. You should be able to use these to display the information you want.

```
Page <?php echo $this->getCurrentPage() ?> of <?php echo $this->getLastPageNum() ?>
```